# Closed form solution for Beurling transform: a 2d integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integral-transforms

Is it possible to find
$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{i\xi}e^{\eta}}{(\alpha-\xi)^2+(\beta-\eta)^2}((\alpha-\xi)+i (\beta-\eta)) \ d\eta d \xi, $$

in closed form?